# Connecting to my online mysql database (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I really need your help guys .... I am trying to make a java program connects to mysql database, and I used to connect with localhost by xampp and its working fine with this code ...

```
public class myConnection {
public static Connection getconnection(){
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?serverTimezone=Turkey","root","");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}
```

}

but now I just bought an online server and made a new datebase Inside it but I have no Idea how to connect my program with it I tried a lot and I searched for many hours but I couldnt find anything about that...  this is my database 
[image]

and this is the code I am trying to use but I always get Communications link failure ..

```
public static Connection getconnection(){
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.bravehost.com/afkodb_3483514","username","password");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}
```

[image]

Comment: try with this "jdbc:mysql://mysql.bravehost.com:3306/afkodb_3483514"

Comment: "The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Communications link failure"  SAME ERROR :( @RahulKumar

Comment: I dont even know if I am using the right url ... is there any way to check if I am using the right url @RahulKumar

Comment: try the below:- 
"jdbc:mysql://sql14.bravehost.com:3306/afkodb_3483514" or
"jdbc:mysql://sql14.bravehost.com/afkodb_3483514"

Comment: I tried them and I tried everything else but still same error .... I searched everywhere in the Internet and I didnt find any solution too @RahulKumar